# Choosing n, m elements from non-disjoint sets A, B such that the selections share same subset of AnB

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

$A$ and $B$ are two non-disjoint sets of size $N$ and $M$, respectively.
How many ways are there of choosing $n$ and $m$ number of elements from $A$ and $B$, respectively, such that the $n$ and $m$ sized selections share the same (potentially empty) subset of *A* $\cap$ *B*? $0 < n \le N, 0 < m \le M$.

I know that this can be solved rather brutishly via a sum.

Take the smaller of $n$ and $m$. For example, let's say $n$ is smaller. Then it's clear that we need to  choose at least $n- \#A \setminus B$ elements from $A \cap B$ in order to be able to choose $n$ elements from $A$. Let us call this minimum number of intersection elements $min\_i$.

Therefore we can sum from $min\_i$ to $\#A \cap B$ and add up the number of ways we can choose said number of intersection elements, multiplied by the number of ways we can choose the remaining elements from $A \setminus B$ and $B \setminus A$:

$$\sum_{i=min\_i}^{\#A \cap B}\binom{\#A \cap B}{i}\binom{\#A \setminus B - i}{n - i}\binom{\#B \setminus A - i}{m - i}$$

This hopefully solves the problem. However, I'm wondering if a more elegant approach exists. In the future, I'll be looking to solve a similar problem for choosing $n$, $m$ and $o$ from $A$, $B$ and $C$ etc, so it's in my interest to solve this initial 2-set case as simply as possible.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: n and m are in the intersection of A and B is not possible unless A and B contain integers which in general they do not.

Comment: Hi @WilliamElliot, I'm not sure if you've understood what I'm asking. I updated the question to hopefully be a bit clearer

Comment: You can get $\le$ using `\le`. You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @joriki

Comment: Now it makes sense.  @ColinMcDonagh

Comment: Sorry for the previous ambiguity @WilliamElliot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn’t be subtracting $i$ in the upper indices of the binomial coefficients; e.g. you always have $\#A\setminus B$ elements to choose from, not $\#A\setminus B-i$. Also, you can let the sum start at $0$, since the extra terms are zero. So the count is

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\#A\cap B}\binom{\#A\cap B}i\binom{\#A\setminus B}{n-i}\binom{\#B\setminus A}{m-i}\;.
$$

I doubt you’ll find a simpler form for that.

Comment: Yikes, of course. Thanks very much